# Abstract classes cannot be instantiated

Tags: java, abstract-class

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated. Then in 
`public void paint(Graphics g){ }` what is the `g` ? Is it not an object? If yes then what are the differences between this and the ones that can be instantiated ?

Comment: [Polymorphism in java](http://java8.in/polymorphism-in-java/) will be helpful for this question...and [Runtime polymorphism](http://java8.in/unit-2-prog-6-inheritance-in-java/) also.

Answer (score 3):

Abstract classes can't be instantiated directly. But their whole point is to be extended by concrete (i.e. non-abstract) classes, which can be instantiated.

So, in your example, `g` is an instance of some GraphicsImpl subclass (this is a madeup name, the actual name is not that one), which extends Graphics and implements all its abstract methods.

Answer (score 0):

`g` is an object from a class that extends the `Graphics` class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can't instantiate an abstract class. Really **g** is an instance of **subclass** of `Graphics`.

Here is sample example how to use it: [Sample example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/gui_text.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, non-abstract subclasses of that abstract class can be instantiated:

```
public abstract class Graphics {
    // new Graphics() would not compile
}

// ...

public class Mygraphics extends Graphics {
    // new Mygraphics() would compile
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes are only partially defined and need further implementation to make them work. To give you an example on the Graphics: There is a different way how to draw a rectangle (lines from 0,0 to 0,b, to a,b, to a,0, to 00), and a circle (line in distance of r from some central point). That means, you cannot define the way they are painted in the Graphics class, but in the class that inherits from it. However, all of them have some already defined properties, which come from the abstract class, e.g. it could be color.

Answer (score 0):

Any class denoted by the abstract keyword can not be instantiated and requires a subclass. You should spend some time and read some theory on Object Orientated programming and what abstract implies (and class hierarchy's in general, specifically class extension).

When in doubt about a class, have a look at the Javadoc, either inline in your IDE or on the web (if it's a public class). For the Graphics class in question (the "g" variable), look here: [Graphics (Java Platform SE 7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html)

To point you in the right direction, you probably want to have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532704/how-to-create-a-graphics2d-instance).